# PHP stdobject with @ symbol for key

Tags: php, arrays

From a json decode, I have an std that has a key called

```
@MyKey
```

Note the `@` symbol prefix. I'm not sure how to access it because doing:

```
$item['@MyKey']
```

Results in

```
 Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

And doing

```
$item->@MyKey
```

Results in

```
 syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

Just figured it out:

```
$item->{'@MyKey'}
```

Comment: Note that you can also decode your json as plain arrays, by passing `true` as second parameter: `json_decode(..., true)`.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the correct answer when you can to help future visitors. Perhaps you could also provide some reference or documentation to explain your solution?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I can't accept my own answer for another two days.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them using the curly syntax. Example:

```
$json = '{ "@test"  : { "@foo" : "bar" }}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->{'@test'}->{'@foo'};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can cast the item to an array and use array accessors as normal

```
$itemArray = (array)$item; 

echo $itemArray["@MyKey"];
```